# I need to update an array of objects with key/value pair only if it does not exists already

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I want to sort through two arrays and determine if any of the objects contain the same key/value pair. Where there is a match by `id`, I want to update the tempSearch array object to include the `shelf` key/value pair from the matched booksOnShelf object. If no match between the arrays, I want to update that tempSearch object with `shelf: "none"`.

I am certain that both arrays have data. Currently, all `shelf` data returns as "none".

**UPDATE** (Including array data example.)

```
tempSearch = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
booksOnShelf = [{id: 1, shelf: "read"}, {id: 4, shelf: "wantToRead"}];
```

The final result of tempSearch:

```
console.log(tempSearch);
// [{id: 1, shelf: "read"}, {id: 2, shelf: "none"}, {id: 3, shelf: "none"}, {id: 4, shelf: "wantToRead"}];
```

**END OF UPDATE**

```
const mergeBooks = () => {
      let tempSearch = searchInventory;
      let booksOnShelf = bookInventory;

      tempSearch.forEach((searchBook, index) => {
        booksOnShelf.forEach(book => {
          if (searchBook.id === book.id) {
            searchBook.shelf = book.shelf;
          } else {
            searchBook.shelf = "none";
          }
        })
      })
      setMergedInventory(tempSearch);
    }
```

Comment: Please add "before" examples of `searchInventory` and `bookInventory` and then also what result you want.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I made the updates requested.

Comment: I've updated my answer, though virtually nothing had to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close, but the issue is that you're assigning to `shelf` in **every** iteration of the inner loop. Instead, find the book, then if you found it, use it, and if not, assign `"none"`:

```
const mergeBooks = () => {
    let tempSearch = searchInventory;
    let booksOnShelf = bookInventory;

    tempSearch.forEach((searchBook) => {
        const book = booksOnShelf.find((book) => book.id === searchBook.id);
        searchBook.shelf = book && book.shelf ? book.shelf : "none";
    });
    setMergedInventory(tempSearch);
};
```

```js
const searchInventory = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
const bookInventory = [{id: 1, shelf: "read"}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, shelf: "wantToRead"}];

const mergeBooks = () => {
    let tempSearch = searchInventory;
    let booksOnShelf = bookInventory;

    tempSearch.forEach((searchBook) => {
        const book = booksOnShelf.find((book) => book.id === searchBook.id);
        searchBook.shelf = book && book.shelf ? book.shelf : "none";
    });
    // setMergedInventory(tempSearch);
    console.log(tempSearch);
};

mergeBooks();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That said, a couple of notes:

1. These days, I'd use a `for-of` loop instead of the `forEach` method.
2. There doesn't seem to be any reason for the `tempSearch` / `booksOnShelf` variables, they just refer to the same things that `serachInventory` and `bookInventory` refer to, so you can just remove them.

So with those changes:

```
const mergeBooks = () => {
    for (const searchBook of searchInventory) {
        const book = bookInventory.find((book) => book.id === searchBook.id);
        searchBook.shelf = book ? book.shelf : "none";
    }
    setMergedInventory(searchInventory);
};
```

```js
const searchInventory = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
const bookInventory = [{id: 1, shelf: "read"}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, shelf: "wantToRead"}];

const mergeBooks = () => {
    for (const searchBook of searchInventory) {
        const book = bookInventory.find((book) => book.id === searchBook.id);
        searchBook.shelf = book && book.shelf ? book.shelf : "none";
    }
    // setMergedInventory(searchInventory);
    console.log(searchInventory);
};

mergeBooks();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

You could also replace the conditional operator (`? :`) with [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator):

```
const mergeBooks = () => {
    for (const searchBook of searchInventory) {
        const book = bookInventory.find((book) => book.id === searchBook.id);
        searchBook.shelf = book?.shelf ?? "none";
    }
    setMergedInventory(searchInventory);
};
```

```js
const searchInventory = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
const bookInventory = [{id: 1, shelf: "read"}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, shelf: "wantToRead"}];

const mergeBooks = () => {
    for (const searchBook of searchInventory) {
        const book = bookInventory.find((book) => book.id === searchBook.id);
        searchBook.shelf = book?.shelf ?? "none";
    }
    // setMergedInventory(searchInventory);
    console.log(searchInventory);
};

mergeBooks();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

If you're a fan of really condensed code (I'm not), that means you don't need the `book` constant anymore:

```
const mergeBooks = () => {
    for (const searchBook of searchInventory) {
        searchBook.shelf = bookInventory.find((book) => book.id === searchBook.id)?.shelf ?? "none";
    }
    setMergedInventory(searchInventory);
};
```

```js
const searchInventory = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
const bookInventory = [{id: 1, shelf: "read"}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, shelf: "wantToRead"}];

const mergeBooks = () => {
    for (const searchBook of searchInventory) {
        searchBook.shelf = bookInventory.find((book) => book.id === searchBook.id)?.shelf ?? "none";
    }
    // setMergedInventory(searchInventory);
    console.log(searchInventory);
};

mergeBooks();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

---

If `bookInventory` is a **very** large array, it's not ideal to search through it using a linear search for each book in `searchInventory`. Instead, you can create a `Map` of ids to books. Looking in a `Map` is a sublinear operation (meaning it takes less time, on average, than searching through one by one). Of course, you have the added overhead of building the `Map`, so it's a balance.

With that:

```
const mergeBooks = () => {
    // Build the Map
    const booksById = new Map(bookInventory.map((book) => [book.id, book]));
    // Use it in the process
    for (const searchBook of searchInventory) {
        const book = booksById.get(searchBook.id);
        searchBook.shelf = book?.shelf ?? "none";
    }
    setMergedInventory(searchInventory);
};
```

```js
const searchInventory = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];
const bookInventory = [{id: 1, shelf: "read"}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4, shelf: "wantToRead"}];

const mergeBooks = () => {
    // Build the Map
    const booksById = new Map(bookInventory.map((book) => [book.id, book]));
    // Use it in the process
    for (const searchBook of searchInventory) {
        const book = booksById.get(searchBook.id);
        searchBook.shelf = book?.shelf ?? "none";
    }
    // setMergedInventory(searchInventory);
    console.log(searchInventory);
};

mergeBooks();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

It might even be useful to maintain `bookInventory` as a `Map` rather than holding it as an array, if you regularly need to look up books in it by ID.